# How to change the hostname of a container before cretion?

Tags: docker, host, etcd

I am looking for a way to change the hostname information in a container. I am running an application that looks for a specific host to connect to another container. Is there a way to achieve this from the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `--add-host` parameter of the `run` command to modify `/etc/hosts` of the container. This will allow you to resolve IP address to what ever name you define.

For example say I want to connect to redis from my python app, but don't want to change the script inside conatiner. Then I can do something like this:

`docker run --add-host=redis:10.0.0.1 my-container`

Then in my script I can connect to redis by passing name `redis` instead of an IP address.